# Fetching WCF service configuration for proxy configuration

Tags: wcf, configuration, proxy, client

Is there a way to fetch information from a WCF service meta-data endpoint to know how to configure the proxy client so that you don't have to configure the proxy client manually? So instead of editing the client proxy configuration, it makes a call to the target service's meta-data, fetch the bindings, etc. and caches it on the client side and so when it makes calls to the service, it should be happy.

Thanks

Comment: That's basically what happens when you choose "Add / Update Service Reference" in Visual Studio... What configuration are you actually talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [MetadataResolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.metadataresolver.aspx) class for this purpose but be aware that this will make your service call much slower. Also it is not silver bullet. Not all features are automatically configured so using this is not very usual. Why don't you like configuring the proxy manually or by *Add service reference*? It is not very common for service to change its configuration frequently.

Comment: Hi Ladislav. It's not that I don't like configuring it, I'm exploring some avenues to make things simpler. I understand the performance implications on this, which is why I mentioned caching that information. If it doesn't fetch all the necessary data, then it might not be as you say a 'silver bullet' solution. I do think however, that it might be useful for certain scenarios. Thanks for your answer.